# How to add variable integer in String number" ";

Tags: java, android, string, variables

I'm new to programming. I am learning how to add variable integer with `String number = " ";`  below is an example. I'm testing.

```
Button buttonSend;
int phone =9900990;

public void onClick(View v) {  
    switch (v.getId()) {     
        case R.id.buttonSend:     
            String messageToSend = "#abc";
            String number = " ";
            SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, messageToSend, null, null);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You shouldn't keep a phone number as an int. The best format is a string. Imagine the number starts with 0; as an int, the number will lose any leftmost zeros.

Comment: @Piovezan -  thank you for the advice. I did not even know about this. It is very useful info to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button buttonSend;
int phone =9900990;

public void onClick(View v) {  

    switch (v.getId()) {     

        case R.id.buttonSend:     
             String messageToSend = "#abc";
             String number = " " + phone;

             SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, messageToSend, null,null);
             break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this.

```
String str = String.valueOf(9900990)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I think you want:

```
String number = String.valueOf(phone);
```

Or

```
String number = "" + phone;
```

Or

```
String number = Integer.toString(phone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the stuff you are looking for(as per feeling from your question)

```
String number = " " + 9900990;
```

But cleaner way is to convert integer to string

```
 String str = String.valueOf(9900990)
```